# Why is Implicit Differentiation needed for Derivative of $y = \arcsin (2x+1)$?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

my function is: $y = \arcsin (2x+1)$ and I want to find its derivative.

My approach was to apply the chain rule:

$$y' = \frac{dg}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$$

with $g = \arcsin(u)$ and $u = 2x+1$.

$$g' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}.$$

${u}' = 2$.

My solution therefore was
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \cdot 2 = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-(2x+1)^2}}.$$

This seems to be wrong and the correct solution is given by: 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^{2}-x}}$

I know that implicit differentiation should be used for this particular problem, but I do not really understand why. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Implicit differentiation is how you'd solve it if you didn't know the antiderivative of $\arcsin(u)$.  Since you do, it's not necessary.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but you should probably simplify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution is correct; they just simplified it further:
\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - (2x + 1)^2}}
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - (4x^2 + 4x + 1)}} \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{-4x^2 - 4x}} \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{4(-x^2 - x)}} \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{4}\sqrt{-x^2 - x}} \\
&= \frac{2}{2\sqrt{-x^2 - x}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2 - x}} \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-(1+2x)^2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4x^2+
-4x-1}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{-4x^2-4x}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4(-x^2-x)}}=\frac{2}{2\sqrt{-x^2-x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2-x}}$$